# Can I request YouTube to let my site play restricted embedded video?

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, embed

I am working on a site that will allow users to upload their videos on my site, for example a dance performance. I am using `<iframe></iframe>` to embed video. Everything was going fine, but suddenly I noticed YouTube is restricting some videos to play on my site.

In my case the error was:

[image: YouTube restricting playing embedded video]

I know some users have asked similar questions like 'why it is happening' etc. I know it has to do with some copyright issues, for example a dance performance may have a background music playing which happens to be someone others property. The thing is, I am not 'claiming' copyrights and even, not me but my users will upload their videos from their YouTube accounts(using URL).

So Is there anyway to play all those videos like if I can request YouTube to let my site play those videos with a disclaimer explaining that my site doesn't have copyrights of these videos?

Answer (score 0):

Does using iframe to point at the non-embedded youtube widget work? If so you could use javascript to extract the player from the regular youtube.

Not sure about the legality of that.

What are you trying to do? Potentially you could use the youtube api and make a mobile app that is not embedding videos.

Comment: currently I am only using the embed link from the youtube site for testing purpose, I thought later at some point of time i will edit that embed link with a new video id. sample embed code `<iframe class="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="580" height="326" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/BO4gEGhLaqA? autoplay=0&modestbranding=1&theme=light&controls=0&showinfo=0&theme=light"frameborder="0"/></iframe>`. have not tried 'youtube widget', do you think it would work?